# Jpa repository find all with type HashSet

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

In my Spring Boot application, I have two entities user and authorities. There are three parameters ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, and ROLE_SYSTEM is assignable to the user as Authority and one user can have multiple authorities. in the user entity I have created join column which joins user and authority, so I can assign multiple authority to a user using Join table, the Entity field is shown below:

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "jhi_user_authority",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "authority_name", referencedColumnName = "name")})
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@BatchSize(size = 20)
private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
```

so, using this field hibernate created the third table which has a user id and authority role. In Repository, I have used Hibernate JPARepository. and using findAll() I am getting all users.
Controller:

In Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/users")
@Timed
@Secured({ AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.SYSTEM })
public ResponseEntity<List<UserDTO>> getAllUsers(Pageable pageable) {

final Page<UserDTO> page = userService.getAllManagedUsers(pageable);
HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/users");
return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

In Service:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<UserDTO> getAllManagedUsers(Pageable pageable) {
return userRepository.findAll(pageable).map(UserDTO::new);
}
```

In Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    Page<User> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

I have tried with this in the repository:

```
 @Query("select users from User users where users.authorities = 'ROLE_USER'")
 Page<User> getAllByAuthoriy(Pageable pageable);
```

Authority entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jhi_authority")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Authority implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @NotNull
   @Size(max = 50)
   @Id
   @Column(length = 50)
   private String name;

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

So, Now I have to change the query from findAll to findAllByAuthorities(Pageable pageable, set authorities). but this not works, showing type casting error.
How to fetch all that user which role is ROLE_USER?

Comment: For starters you don't need that `findAll` method as that is provided by default. The `findAllByAuthorities` has the arguments in the wrong order. The `Pageable` argument must be last.

Comment: i have updated question, can you please check it? it's showing  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException exception, how to pass set<> in a query?

Comment: Unclear. 'ROLE_USER' is a string. Authority is an entity. A string can't be equal to an entity. Post the Authority entity, and tell us what to compare in Authority with 'ROLE_USER'. In any case, you need a join: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join

Comment: `select u from User u join u.authorities a where a.name = 'ROLE_USER'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution,
I have to write a query for getting users from user table which authority is a user_role. for that, I have to pass a string to match in HashSet.

```
@Query("select users from User users where 'ROLE_USER' member of users.authorities")
Page<User> getAllByAuthoriy(Pageable pageable);
```